# Mysql Count Rows "Above" Selected Based on Order

Tags: mysql, sql

On my earnings website, some of my users want to know what "rank" they are for today's earnings. If they have the second most earnings for today, they would be ranked #2.

The only way I can think to do this in Mysql is `Select user FROM stats WHERE date=today ORDER BY earnings` and then loop through the results until the desired user is found.

This seems like a lot of work for a somewhat simple operation. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: They also want to know how much more they need to earn to move up a rank.

Edit2: Another problem with the system above is that everyone with $0 earnings would be a different rank, when ideally I would want them to be tied with the same rank.

Edit3: Perhaps if I could make some sort of view where an auto-increment ID was assigned based on the ORDER of earnings, then your ID would also be your rank. I could also easily reference the person above the user with ID-1. Is this possible?

Edit4: Thanks to richardthekiwi, I have come up with the real query for anyone interested:

```
SELECT  
count(*)+1 MyRanking,
IFNULL((SELECT earnings from today_stats rankUp WHERE rankUp.earnings > my.earnings ORDER BY rankUp.earnings LIMIT 1)-my.earnings,0) AS rankdiff,
my.earnings
FROM today_stats my
left join today_stats others on others.earnings > my.earnings
WHERE my.user_id=18132
```

Comment: You can use `coalesce( min( others.earnings ) - min( my.earnings ), 0 ) as rankdiff ` instead of subquery (coalesce changing null for 1st rank to 0 ) and if you want all ties have the same rank use `count( distinct others.earnings )+1` instead of your count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to find the rank of a SINGLE user, with ties, then you can use this query

```
   select count(*)+1 MyRanking
     from stats my
left join stats others on others.earnings > my.earnings
    where username = 'abcdef';
```

To find how much they need to move up, just look for the next higher earning, e.g.

```
   select IFNULL(others.earnings - my.earnings, 0) DifferenceToNext
     from stats my
left join stats others on others.earnings > my.earnings
    where username = 'abcdef'
 order by others.earnings asc
    limit 1;
```

An index on `stats.earnings` will go a long way for both these queries.  A separate index on username will help for the first.

Comment: Thanks! Working on this now...anyway to get both in the same query?

Comment: There is little cost to running two queries, so even though the answer is yes, I would rather not complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to your **Edit 3**:

I'm not sure whether it solves your problem, but in `mySql` it is very easy to create a pseudo-column with auto-incremental `ID`.

```
SET @ID=0;
SELECT @ID=@ID+1, s.* 
FROM Status s
WHERE ...
ORDER BY earnings;
```

Comment: Great! I can easily get the user's rank with this! What about referencing the user right above you though? I cannot use a WHERE rank=